# can you address single bits of an int?

Tags: c

As I understand it, addressing a single bit in an int variable seems possible, if it is passed as a pointer. Am I correct?

```
uint8_t adcState[8];
uint16_t adcMessageId[8];

void adcEnable(uint8_t* data) {
    // Set ADC Input as enabled
    adcState[(uint8_t) data[0]] = 1;

    // Get ADC Message ID
    adcMessageId[(uint8_t) data[0]] = data[2] << 8 | data[1];
}
```

So far this is what I figured out that:

1. The function receives a pointer to 8bit int as an argument
2. It takes the least significant digit of that int (the pointer is treated as an array, and its first field is being read), and uses it as a field number for `adcState` array, which then is set to `1`. For example this would mean if data was `729`, the `data[0]` would be `'9'` and therefore the `adcsState[9]` becomes `1`.
   Is it possible? Can you use the pointers like this?
3. For the `adcMessageId` array a similar approach is taken. However here the value it is assigned depends on the third and second digit of the data int.

   I don't understand the shift over here. Being a `uint8_t` value it has only 8 bits, so shifting with 8 bits always gives 0000 0000. Therefore an OR with `data[1]` would be just `data[1]` itself...
   In our example, the `adcMessageId[9]` would become (`'7' << 8`) bitwise OR with `'2'`, so just `'2'`.

Something in my logic seems wrong.

Comment: `data[2]` is promoted to `int` before shifting, so the bits are not lost.

Comment: The casts to `uint8_t` before `data[0]` in this code are superfluous btw, and are just making this code hard to read.

Comment: "data[0] would be '9' and therefore the adcsState[9] becomes '1'" No. `adcsState[57]` will be set, which is clearly out of bounds. Same as `adcsState[9]` would be.

Comment: Your usage of input data is not really clear. Please provide at least an example of a call to that function that shows what kind of data you feed into it.

Comment: `... = (data[2] << 8) | data[1];` <<-- add parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The function receives a pointer to 8bit int as an argument

Yes, roughly.  And the function implementation assumes that the pointed-to `uint8_t` can be treated as the first element of an array of at least three `uint8_t`.

> 2. It takes the least significant digit of that int (the pointer is treated as an array, and its first field is being read), and uses it
>    as a field number for `adcState` array, which then is set to `1`. For
>    example this would mean if `data` was `729`, the `data[0]` would be '9' and
>    therefore the `adcsState[9]` becomes '1'. Is it possible? Can you use
>    the pointers like this?

No, you have completely misunderstood.  `data[0]` means exactly the same thing as `*data`.  It refers to the 8-bit unsigned integer to which `data` points.  The number 729 is too large to be represented as a `uint8_t`, but if the object to which `data` pointed had the value 129 then `data[0]` would evaluate to 129.

You are perhaps confused by the appearance later in the function of `data[1]` and `data[2]`.  These refer to two `uint8_t` objects following `*data` in memory, such as will reliably be present if `data` points to the first element of an array, as I alluded to above.  Indexing with `[]` does not have the effect of slicing the `uint8_t` to which `data` points.

Pay attention also that I am saying "the object to which `data` points".  One does not pass a `uint8_t` value directly as this function's parameter.  It is not anticipating that an integer value would be reinterpreted as a pointer.  You pass a pointer to the data you want the function to work with.

> 3. For the `adcMessageId` array a similar approach is taken. However here the value it is assigned depends on the third and second digit of
>    the `data` int.

In the `adcMessageId` case, again `data[0]` refers to the `uint8_t` to which `data` points.  `data[1]` refers to another whole `uint8_t` following that in memory, and `data[2]` to the next after that.

> I don't understand the shift over here. Being a uint8_t value it has only 8 bits, so shifting with 8 bits always gives 0000 0000.

`uint8_t` has only 8 bits, but all integer values narrower than `int` are converted to an integer type at least as wide as `int`, or perhaps to a floating-point type, for arithmetic operations.  The specific promoted type depends in part on what the other operand is, and the result has the same, promoted type.  Type `int` is at least 16 bits wide on all conforming C implementations.  Thus this ...

> ```
> data[2] << 8 | data[1]
> ```

... intends to pack the two `uint8_t` values `data[2]` and `data[1]` into one 16-bit integer, `data[2]` in the most-significant position.  It's not entirely safe because the elements of `data` will be promoted to (`signed`) `int` instead of `unsigned int`, but that will present an issue only on implementations where `int` is 16 bits wide (which are uncommon these days), and even then, only if the value of `data[2]` is larger than 127.  A safer way to express it would involve explicit casts:

```
(unsigned int) data[2] << 8 | (unsigned int) data[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

It would seem `data` is pointing to an array, not a single 8 bit `int`, and that:

1. The first element of the array is a pointer into the arrays `adcState` and `adcMessageId`
2. The second and third elements of the array comprise a data value for the array `adcMessageId`
3. As commenter @Eugene Sh. pointed out, `data[2]` is promoted to an `int` before shifting, so no bits are lost.

The pointer notation `uint8_t *` is as valid as array notation `uint8_t []` in a function signature for passing an array; it's often how `char *` strings are passed, and arrays decay to a pointer to their first element when passed to functions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few misconceptions. Or maybe just wrong wording.

> The function receives a pointer to 8bit int as an argument

More precisely it gets a pointer to an array of 8bit integers. Otherwise your usage would be invalid. Probably it gets a pointer to a string.

> It takes the least significant digit of that int (the pointer is treated as an array, and its first field is being read),

That is wrong. You seem to use it as a pointer to a string holding a number.
In that case you access the first character, which is the MOST significant decimal digit.

> and uses it as a field number for adcState array, which then is set to 1. For example this would mean if data was 729, the data[0] would be '9' and therefore the adcsState[9] becomes '1'. Is it possible? Can you use the pointers like this?

You are messing up things a bit.
If you want to access decimal digits, we are talking about strings and there the first element is `'7'` which is not to be confused with `7`.

> For the adcMessageId array a similar approach is taken. However here the value it is assigned depends on the third and second digit of the data int.

Maybe you should not talk about int if you are using strings.

> I don't understand the shift over here. Being a uint8_t value it has only 8 bits, so shifting with 8 bits always gives 0000 0000. Therefore an OR with data[1] would be just data[1] itself... In our example, the adcMessageId[9] would become ('7' << 8) bitwise OR with '2', so just '2'.

That was already addressed in comments and [Govind Parmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281552/can-you-address-single-bits-of-an-int/66281677#66281677): Integer promotion takes place before shifting.